# React trying to loop through state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to create a component that onclick of a button gets appended to a parent component of DOM element. However I am having a problem getting the initial loop working. Here is what I am doing,

```
 class GenerateInvoice extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      'invoice': {
        'items' : {}
      }
    };

    this.onAddChild = this.onAddChild.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    const children = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.state.invoice.items); i += 1) {
      children.push(<InvoiceItemForm key={i} number={i} />);
    };
    return(
      <div>
        <a href="" onClick={this.onAddChild}>Add New Item</a>
        {children}
      </div>
    )
  }

  onAddChild = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    let invoice = this.state.invoice.items;
    this.setState({ invoice : {'id' : 'INV001'} });
  }


}

export default GenerateInvoice ;
```

However when I client the button with onAddChild callback on it, I get

> Cannot convert undefined or null to object

why would this be?

Here is a link to my test project,

https://codesandbox.io/s/0qx9w1qrwv

Comment: Your state objects keys don't need to be strings

Comment: @KarlTaylor: They aren't. The *property names* are given as strings, true, which is optional but harmless.

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Side note: The loop creating the children is markedly inefficient, and it's **really** strange to be using the *index* of the property name in an object (`i` in that loop) for...well...for just about anything. I suspect `this.state.invoice.items` should be an array, not an object. Also note that the block attached to a control statement (`if`, `for`, etc.) doesn't take a `;` at the end. (The parser will ignore it because it allows *EmptyStatement*, but it doesn't belong there.)

Comment: Could you please explain why it is inefficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your state here:

```
let invoice = this.state.invoice.items;
this.setState({ invoice : {'id' : 'INV001'} });
```

after that call your state will be

```
{ invoice: {'id': 'INV001'} }
```

and the items property will be gone.

If you are trying to add an item, something like this would work:

```
let invoice = this.state.invoice;
// creates an updated version of the items without changing the original value
let updatedItems = invoice.items.concat({'id': 'INV001'});
// creates a new version of the invoice with the updated items
let updateInvoice = { ...invoice, items: updatedItems };
// update the invoice on the state to the new version
this.setState({ invoice });
```

Comment: This is assuming items is changed to an array as T.J. Crowder suggested above

Comment: Changed to array and it works great :), though I would like some input as to why my loop is inefficient?